# How to log exact session out datetime in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session

To display the duration for the user session on his next login summery, Saving the session start timing to the database after immediate login. Here setting `SessionId` as session variable for inserted entry. This `SessionId` in session should be alive while logging out/session out.
After hitting the logout button, I can update the same session entry against the session variable. But what if session getting timeout automatically according to `web.config` Timeout.

I tried to update same entry in `Global.asax` in `Session_End` Event. But never triggered though session out.(don't know why). But is there a way to calculate the User session timespan in .NET?

Comment: Finally I got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally On Each Master page load I added follwoing script which call the Service method to update the session information.

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           var sessionTimeout = '<%= Session.TimeOut %>'; //Web.config timeout
           var sessionTimeoutWarning = parseInt(sessionTimeout) - 1; //Trigger time before 1 min of expire
           var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
           var sessionId = '<%= session("SessionId") %>'; //This is kept in session when user logged in and entry created in database.
           setTimeout(function() {
               if (sessionId > 0) {
                   ClientService.UpdateClientSessionInformation(sessionId); //This is the client service method to update against session Id. Rest of time out and time span is manged in Stored procedure.
                                  }
           }, sTimeout);       
   </script>
```